# Can't load mysqlnd extension in php:fpm-alpine

Tags: php, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, docker-image

I'm trying to setup a php image based on php:fpm-alpine.
I want for php to use the mysqlnd extension. Better put: I want the file mysqlnd.so to be in the extension folder `/usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20190902`. Somehow this seems to be the folder, where `.so`-files are stored.

I have an .ini file in the php conf.d folder for enabling the extension:

```
; configuration for php mysql module
; priority=10
extension=mysqlnd
```

My Dockerfile looks like this:

```
FROM php:fpm-alpine

RUN apk update --no-cache \
    && apk add --no-cache $PHPIZE_DEPS \
    && apk add --no-cache php-mysqlnd \
    && docker-php-ext-install mysqlnd \
    && docker-php-ext-enable mysqlnd
```

When I try to build the image, it stops with this output (only relevant part):

```
#5 7.687 fetch http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.12/main/x86_64/APKINDEX.tar.gz
#5 7.820 fetch http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.12/community/x86_64/APKINDEX.tar.gz
#5 7.980 (1/3) Installing php7-common (7.3.24-r0)
#5 8.000 (2/3) Installing php7-openssl (7.3.24-r0)
#5 8.021 (3/3) Installing php7-mysqlnd (7.3.24-r0)
#5 8.048 OK: 255 MiB in 59 packages
#5 9.541 fetch http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.12/main/x86_64/APKINDEX.tar.gz
#5 9.819 fetch http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.12/community/x86_64/APKINDEX.tar.gz
#5 10.15 (1/1) Installing .phpize-deps (20201122.190848)
#5 10.16 OK: 255 MiB in 60 packages
#5 10.22 Cannot find config.m4. 
#5 10.22 Make sure that you run '/usr/local/bin/phpize' in the top level source directory of the module
#5 10.22 
------
```

Error is basically:

**`#5 10.22 Cannot find config.m4.`**

**`Make sure that you run '/usr/local/bin/phpize' in the top level source directory of the module`**

I also created a functioning image without mysqlnd and tried to install it manually from the cli of the cointainer. It didn't work either.

Help would be highly appreciated, because I can't seem to get it working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happens because you just don't have to install it, [it is there already](https://github.com/docker-library/php/blob/d8d798be28c49ced47d772aa899c0a1febabdba3/7.1/alpine3.4/fpm/Dockerfile#L120)

Running this commands

```sh
docker run -ti php:fpm-alpine php -i | grep mysqlnd
```

Yields this output:

> ```
> Configure Command =>  './configure'  '--build=x86_64-linux-musl' '--with-config-file-path=/usr/local/etc/php' '--with-config-file-scan-dir=/usr/local/etc/php/conf.d' '--enable-option-checking=fatal' '--with-mhash' '--with-pic' '--enable-ftp' '--enable-mbstring' '--enable-mysqlnd' '--with-password-argon2' '--with-sodium=shared' '--with-pdo-sqlite=/usr' '--with-sqlite3=/usr' '--with-curl' '--with-libedit' '--with-openssl' '--with-zlib' '--with-pear' '--enable-fpm' '--with-fpm-user=www-data' '--with-fpm-group=www-data' '--disable-cgi' 'build_alias=x86_64-linux-musl'
> mysqlnd
> mysqlnd => enabled
> Version => mysqlnd 7.4.12
> Loaded plugins => mysqlnd,debug_trace,auth_plugin_mysql_native_password,auth_plugin_mysql_clear_password,auth_plugin_caching_sha2_password,auth_plugin_sha256_password
> ```

Where the important part is:

> ```
> mysqlnd => enabled
> Version => mysqlnd 7.4.12
> ```

Comment: I figured it out on my own couple of minutes ago. My problem was the .ini file. Because it looked for a mysqlnd.so file in the folder for dynamically added modules.
I ended up using https://github.com/mlocati/docker-php-extension-installer for easier installation of modules.
For mysqlnd I just deleted the .ini file, because it is included anyways.

Nevertheless I want to thank you :)